# python regular expression to search regular pattern in file

Tags: python-2.7

I want a function to find a pattern(word character) on each line inside a file. my code is sort of working but it does not go further after reading the first line. can anyone help? import re

```
    inputtext = open('input.txt', 'r+')
    inputtext1 = inputtext.read()


    match = re.search(r'([matchwordinline].*\n)+', inputtext1)



    if match:

            match1 = match.group()
    print match1
```

Answer (score 1):

re.search matches only one instance.. Try re.findall

```
list_name = re.findall(r'([matchwordinline].*\n)+', inputtext1)
```

For more 
Visit https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=matching%20searching#finding-all-adverbs

```
import re
inputtext = open('input.txt', 'r+')
inputtext1 = inputtext.read()

match = re.findall(r'([your word].*\n)+', inputtext1)
print match
```

This is my input.txt

```
cat
alicecat deaf
cut cat crazy
buttercup ruin
youseeacatidont
```

When I search for word cat i got the following output

```
['cat\n', 'cat deaf\n', 'cat crazy\n', 'catidont\n']
```

Hope this is what you meant..

Comment: your suggestion did not help. re.findall will find only the matching word. I want a given pattern following the rest of the line.

Comment: You said you want a given pattern following the rest of the line.

Comment: @user3395021 The rest of the line is available in it. Check again :)